# can't show error message into error function in ajax - django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i'm trying to show error message from server to client site using ajax , but it wont work when i make a function for error messages ,

```
     #other codes for saving the post,there is not error
     success_meesage = f'success'
     return JsonResponse({'success':'success','success_msg':success_meesage})
 else:
     error_message=f'there is an error into your two dates please make sure check in smaller than check out'
     return JsonResponse({'success':False,'error_taken':True,'error_message':error_message})
```

my ajax code

```js
    const form = document.getElementById('post-form')
    form.addEventListener("submit",submitHanler);
    function submitHanler(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"my-url",
            data:$("#post-form").serialize(),
            dataType:'json',
            success:successFunction,
            error:errorFunction,
                        
        })        
    }
    function successFunction(data){
        // console.log(data)
        if(data.success='success' && data.success_msg){
            form.reset();
            alertify.success(data.success_msg)
        }
    }
    function errorFunction(request, status, error){
        console.log(request.responseText)
 
        if(error.error_taken == true){
            alertify.alert('warning !','message')
            alertify.alert(error.error_message,function(){

            });
        }
           

        }

    }
```

i also tried this : `function errorFunction(jqXHR, exception)`
it shows nothing as well , i tried many ways but none of them worked !
thank you in advance ..

Comment: is the errorFunction being called at all?

Comment: You need to return a non 200-399 status code, so: `return JsonResponse({'success':False,'error_taken':True,'error_message':error_message}, status=400)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `JsonResponse`, but with status code 200, so that means that, according to the status code, the request was successful.

We thus can return a `JsonResponse` with a status code outside the 200-399 range, for example a 400 HTTP response:

```
if some_condition:
    success_meesage = f'success'
    return JsonResponse(
        {'success':'success','success_msg':success_meesage}
    )
else:
    error_message=f'there is an error into your two dates please make sure check in smaller than check out'
    return JsonResponse(
        {'success':False,'error_taken':True,'error_message':error_message},
        status=400
    )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68909508/how-to-pass-parameter-to-url-into-the-template-to-redirect-to-a-specific-categor can this be fixed please ? thank yo